# Efficient SELECT of one per type from a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c877

As an example, lets just say it's a table of 'activities' that are done by 'users'.

What is the most efficient method of SELECTING one random row per user_id from the table?

For example, given the above table, my select would return 5 rows. One for `user_id` **3**, one for **4**, one for **8**, one for **23** and one for **90**.

I'm using PHP for this application so one thing I was thinking was to just query a bit list of all activities, then loop through them in PHP and randomly pull out one row per user_id that way. This would result in only one SELECT call to the MySQL server.

Alternatively I think this could be done in a series of sub-selects, but I'm not sure how to setup the syntax for that. And I'm not sure if that would be slower anyways...

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512542/select-random-rows-but-without-duplicates-of-values-from-one-column

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck using mysql, because there's a special "trick" mysql allows:

```
select user_id, activity
from activities
group by user_id;
```

See [this query in sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c877/1).

In mysql (only, afaik) you don't have to have non group-by columns aggregated, and when you do this, mysql returns the (first* row it finds for each group.

In all other databases I know this query would instead cause a syntax error.

Now, although this query theoretically gives you random rows - the SQL standard says that when not ordered, rows may be in any order - in reality this query will return the same "random" row for each user, unless you change the row order on disk by doing some inserts/deletes.

IF you truely want "random -ie different every time - rows for each user, you need to use this uqery to select from a row set that is randomly ordered, like this:

```
select user_id, activity
from (select * from activities order by rand()) x
group by user_id;
```

See [this query in sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c877/14)

Comment: @njk Bad practice? What *exactly* is "bad practice" about this answer?   Sure it's mysql specific, but it's documented behaviour for mysql. This kind of query is used in production code all over the world. I used to think like you, but then I realised just how handy this really is.

Comment: It is not ANSI standard and forbidden in every other DBMS. If the OP would migrate to another DBMS, his query would be invalid.

Comment: @njk The answer clearly says this is not standard SQL so that risk is there for him to accept. Also, how many migrations to other databases have you ever done? In my career (20+ years) I have done it once. People just don't move databases - it's not actually very common at all.

Comment: So there is no other alternative?

Comment: @njk Yes. There is: You can use *User Defined Variables*, and the query is much more complicated and that too is mysql specific. This answer is definitely the most efficient and it's straightforward, supported and documented. And if you down-voted this answer, you should down-vote the other copied/identical answer too.

Answer (score 0):

you cant try this query:

```
select * from (
select activity, user_id from activities order by rand()
) as x group by user_id;
```

first query will order the record randomly, and second query will return just top row for each user_id.